# Container doesn't contain anything

Tags: html, css

I have a page and I want the page width to adjust to the browser. I thought that if a start a `div`, named 'container' for example, and I put the whole page in it and tell the `div` to completely fill the browsers width with `width: 100%;` then it will all resize. But it doesn't, the `div` doesn't even contain the page even thought it is inside it.

```
<header>
  <div id="header"> 
    <table width="100%" border="0">
       ...
    </table>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: trying putting the width: 100% on the div instead of the table.

Comment: the div also have width to 100%

Comment: +1 for width: 100% in the div -- css is inheritance based, so the children are only as wide as their parent.

Comment: @Mortando "the div also have width to 100%" - not according to the code that you pasted...

Comment: well i pasted just the html, i set the width in css that is linked to it

Comment: @Mortando via a class?

Comment: Save us all, make a jsfiddle.

Comment: You talk about a div named "container", I can't see this div in your example. If you put a div in a blank page with width 100% you'll see that it does work. My trick is to set a background color to see what is hapenning to the div.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RhCfp/ so i want it to fit the browser width...but  i cant make it resize the page because it resize itself but not the thing that "contains"

Comment: could you provide some fake image or a cleaner /usable snippet ? try a background color on your div and find out the behavior of tables ( http://jsfiddle.net/RhCfp/1/ )

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RhCfp/6/ here, it will probably work, and another question now that i see. How can i put the text: "Bun venit la noi pe site!" over the black image?

Comment: And what have you done? now i realised that the container dont have a specific width or something

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're looking for comes from `display:block`. This is happening already by default - it's just a matter of [understanding how it works](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/).

There are already two elements above/outside of your `div` that you can experiment with.

Try doing this in your CSS:

```
html {
    background: orange;
}
body {
    background: blue;
}
```

Then give this style to your `div`:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    background: white;
}
```

Now, while on your page, press `Control` and `-` (Windows) **or** `Command` and `-` (Mac) on your keyboard a few times. Notice how the background colors behave.

Finally, set `width:100%;` on your `div` instead of the value I listed above.

Experiment with combinations of these and eventually you'll see that:

- Some elements are `display:block` by default.
- All `display:block` elements use every bit of available width, unless told to do otherwise.
- The "available width" of each element is its parent (aka its container).
- The "available width" of the top-most element (`html`) is the width of the window.

Some takeaway notes should be:

- You don't need a div to do this - it's extra code and [not semantic](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/).
- If any element has its width explicitly set to anything other than `100%` **or** it is of a display type other than `block`, then none of its descendants (children, grandchildren, etc.) will have their width be the width of the window.